# UTF8, Unicode and Binary data reading troubles

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have been working in a script to read files, extract and index some strings. Everything is going fine, except for one problem with file encoding.

I will try to resume:

My script read chunk of data from files, convert these chunks to lowercase and normalize to remove replace special characters (ç, á, é, ã, etc) using unicodedata.normalize:

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",chunk.decode("utf8","ignore")).encode("ascii","ignore").lower()
```

In this case, the string "Olá, como vai você? Vamos caçar?" will result in "Ola, como vai voce? Vamos cacar?" It is working fine with UTF8 encoded text files, but it fails when trying to retrieve strings from binary files (like MS .doc files). Using the same code from above, will return me a string "Ol, como vai voc? Vamos caar?"

I have managed to get it working with MS .doc files using the unicode-escape (but it will fail with the UTF8 files).

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",chunk.decode("unicode-escape","ignore")).encode("ascii","ignore").lower()
```

After 20+ hours of research I have no solution yet to get my script running in both cases.

Unfortunatelly I cant use external modules.

Comment: It seems to me that you are doing too much work *before* you call `unicodedata.normalize`. Can you do the normalization before anything else? This should hopefully produce a consistent set of data for the encode/decode to work with.

Comment: Are your "strings from binary files (like MS .doc files)" always UTF-8-encoded? If not, you'll need to decode them with a different coding scheme. AFAIK, there's no way around that. So your code will have to know the encoding of each input (e.g. by knowing its source and that source's encoding.)

Comment: @AustinHastings It doesn't make sense to normalise before decoding. You can't unicode-normalise a bytes sequence.

Comment: Maybe not. But the chunk is both decoded and encoded. I'm suggesting that maybe the encode should come later. What I think is happening is that the conversion to ascii is dropping unconvertable characters (errors="ignore") before the normalizer can convert them to basechar + modifying mark.

Comment: But it does. Look carefully at the parentheses: It's first `decode()`, then `normalise()`, then `encode()` on the result (and finally `lower()`). It's a long, hard-to-read one-liner...

Comment: Ah, you're right. Missed the second paren. NVM.

Comment: Okay, next question: are you sure that the MS doc file is stored in a unicode encoding? It looks like PT-BR, so maybe it's CP860?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! I will try to make the code to look better and try some new stuff. I will post back. Sorry for the confuse code, I am using this script to lean python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parametrize your script. You should specify the encoding as an argument you call it. If you already specify the file name as an argument, it would look like this:

```
$ python your_script.py input-file.txt utf8
```

Read the arguments like this:

```
input_file, encoding = sys.argv[1:]
```

Then change the encoding-mangling line to:

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", chunk.decode(encoding, "ignore")).encode("ascii", "ignore").lower()
```

Maybe there's a way to guess the encoding in some other way (eg. if all files of one kind end with ".doc"), then you can skip the command-line argument.

Comment: Also, this will make it easier to test different encodings – as comments on your question suggest, `unicode-escape` might not be the correct choice for .doc files.